# Unable to show checked radio button inside table

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am trying to get a radio button checked based on the data that was passed from the server to the view. However I cannot get the radio button to be checked inside a bootstrap table. The following is my code:

```
<tbody>
    <?php
    foreach($results as $row)
    {
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row->productCoverNoteNo ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->productClass ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->productName ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row->productPolicyNo ?></td>
        <td>                    
            <input type="radio" name="tbx_paymentStatus" id="paid" value="PAID" <?php if ($row->productPaymentStatus == "UNPAID"){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?>  />
            <label for="paid">Paid</label></br>
            <input type="radio" name="tbx_paymentStatus" id="unpaid" value="UNPAID" <?php if ($row->productPaymentStatus == "PAID"){ echo "checked='checked'"; }?> />
            <label for="unpaid">Unpaid</label>
        </td>
        <td><a title="Edit this customer product" href="<?php echo base_url("customerProduct/editCustomerProduct/$row->productCoverNoteNo") ?>"><i class="fa fa-pencil fa-lg"></i></a>
            | <a title="View endorsements of this customer product" href="<?php echo base_url("endorsement/viewEndorsement/$row->productCoverNoteNo") ?>"><i class="fa fa-book fa-lg"></i></a></td>
    </tr>
    <?php echo($row->productPaymentStatus);
    }
    ?>  
</tbody>
```

Comment: Use echo 'checked="checked"'; there is problem of single quote and double quote

Comment: tried that.. I wont show too.

Comment: Check value of your variable may be it is differed in case

Comment: i echoed <?php echo($row->productPaymentStatus);?> and its correct. I also tried it with "checked" only also. Same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
    `<input type="radio" name="tbx_paymentStatus" id="paid" value="PAID" 
<?php if ($row->productPaymentStatus == "UNPAID"){ ?> checked='checked' <?php }?>  />`